# Watcher for property of WMI class

Tags: c#

I want to include smth like watcher on a property of WMI class Win32_TerminalServiceSetting. So when some other program or user using cmd command "change logon /disable or /enable" my program make some stuff based on "Logons" property of Win32_TerminalServiceSetting class

I have default code for checking property of Win32_TerminalServiceSetting.

```
//create a management scope object
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\CIMV2\\TerminalServices");
    
    //create object query
    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_TerminalServiceSetting");
    
    //create object searcher
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                            new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    
    //get a collection of WMI objects
    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
    
    //enumerate the collection.
    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection) 
    {
      // access properties of the WMI object
      Console.WriteLine("Logons: {0}", m["Logons"]);
      
    }
```

How can i get info about changing this parameter from another program without like while statement on this query execution? I saw there is WqlEventQuery() for getting information about events of wmi classes, but my code don't trigger while i use "change logon /disable or /enable" in cmd. maybe i'm doing smth wrong

```
    public class eventWatcher
    {
        public eventWatcher()
        {
            WqlEventQuery query;
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2\\TerminalServices");
            scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
            try
            {
                query = new WqlEventQuery();
                query.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
                query.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
                query.Condition = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_TerminalServiceSetting'";
                var eventWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
                eventWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(this.HandleEvent);
                eventWatcher.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("got new event");
        }
    }
```

and `new testDLL.eventWatcher();` on start program

Answer (score 0):

You use the following Code:

```
var wrapper = NotifyPropertyChangedWrapper<T>.Wrap(myObject);
var observable = wrapper.WhenAny();
observable.Subscribe(newValue => {
// Handle any property change
});
```

A example si here:
https://github.com/sergio235/Venn